# Differentiation theorem for probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

Given our usual Lebesgue differentiation theorem

$\forall f \in L^2((0,1),B,\lambda)$ we have $$\frac{1}{|[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]|} \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}f(y) dy \rightarrow f(x)$$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

I am wondering if there another such analogous result that tells us about $f \in L^2([0,1),B,\mathbb{P})$, given that $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure satisfying $\mathbb{P}((a,a+\epsilon))\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is continuous singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure the there exists a set $E$ such that $P(E)=1$ and $m(E)=0$.Take $f=I_E$ to see that the limit is $1$ for all $x$ whereas the right side is $0$ a.e. [m]. Here $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Also, if $f=1$ then the limit is $DP(x)$ in the notations of Rudin's RCA and $DP(x)=\infty$ a.e. $[P]$ when $P\perp m$. Hence the result fails very badly for general probability measures.

Comment: Hi Kavi, I am not sure how that helps.

Comment: It is not a general probability measure, if we specify $\mathbb{P}([a,a+\epsilon])\rightarrow 0$, is that not enough?

Comment: $\mathbb P (a,a+\epsilon) \to 0$ for any $\mathbb P$ and  $\mathbb P [a,a+\epsilon] \to 0$ for any contiuous probability measure  $\mathbb P$.